# How can I programatically access bokeh plot styling options (description, default value)

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

As the question states, I need a way to programatically access the description and default value of a plot option, e.g. `plot/width`.

So, is there something that holds all the styling options like `width`, `xrotation`, with its description and default values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.lookup` on the Bokeh model (class or instance) to get ahold of the property's descriptor, then it's accessible via the `__doc__` attribute:

```
In [1]: from bokeh.models import DataRange1d

In [2]: print(DataRange1d.lookup('start').__doc__)

    An explicitly supplied range start. If provided, will override
    automatically computed start value.
```

You may want to `dedent` or strip whitespace from the result, depending on your use-case.

If you have or can create actual default instances of Bokeh models, then you can get the default property value by just inspecting it, i.e. look at the value of `range.start`. This is probably preferable, if possible.

Otherwise, if you only are dealing with the classes, then getting the default value is a little bit trickier:

```
In [7]: d = DataRange1d.lookup('start')

In [8]: print(d.class_default(DataRange1d))
None
```

Note that a few Bokeh models have instance-specific defaults, those can be also accessed like this:

```
In [9]: r = DataRange1d()

In [11]: print(d.instance_default(r))
None
```

But again, if you have an instance, you could also just look at `.start` directly. If you have not set it explicitly, you will see the default value. (Also note in the specific case of `DataRange1d` the class and instance defaults are the same.)

---

**EDIT** Also possibly worth mentioning, there is a script in the project repo that will dump a JSON blob with every Bokeh model and its properties, including defaults, type, etc. Be aware the output of this script is *very large*, but if it is better to have all the information up front in one place, this will provide it:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/scripts/spec.py